# Defining fields and adding features to the output layer in a processing algorithm in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, qgis-3

I have two input vector layers (one point and one line layer). I loop through every feature in the input-line-layer and calculate some things (with the help of the point layer).

What I am trying to do now is to generate an output line layer for which I want to have the following six fields:

```
1. QgsField('id', QVariant.String)
2. QgsField('vto', QVariant.Double)
3. QgsField('vfrom', QVariant.Double)
4. QgsField('priority', QVariant.Int)
5. QgsField('node1', QVariant.String)
6. QgsField('node2', QVariant.String)
```

Based on those defined fields, I want to add some features to the output layer,
but I do not know how to define the fields (of the output layer) and how to add features to the output layer in QGIS3.

Note: I am using the processing algorithm template for QGIS3 from Underdark: see https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/

Based on her template, she writes this:

```
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        inEdges = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, 
                       self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_EDGES, context)
        inNodes = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, 
                       self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_NODES, context)
        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, 
                       self.OUTPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_MERGED, context,
                       inEdges.fields(), inEdges.wkbType(), inEdges.sourceCrs())
```

In the line which starts with (sink, dest_id), underdark has declared an outputlayer that takes the same fields as the inputlayer. But how can I declare an outputlayer with my customized fields (which are not ident with the fields from the inputlayer)?

EDIT:
As suggested from root676, I altered my code a little bit:

```
# 1. First of all, I defined a variable which holds the definition of my fields
outFields = QgsFields()

# 2. Then, I defined the fields
outFields.append(QgsField('id', QVariant.String))
outFields.append(QgsField('vto', QVariant.Double))
outFields.append(QgsField('vfrom', QVariant.Double))
outFields.append(QgsField('priority', QVariant.Int))
outFields.append(QgsField('node1', QVariant.String))
outFields.append(QgsField('node2', QVariant.String))

# 3. Then I created the output sink with the previously defined fields
(sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_MERGED, context,
                                           outFields, inEdges.wkbType(), inEdges.sourceCrs())

# 4. I created a new feature that will be added to the outputlayer after I set its attribute values.
newEdge = QgsFeature()

# 5. The ERROR happens when I try to set an attribute value like this:
newEdge['id'] = edgeIdTrimmed
```

The error I am getting is as followed:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 143, in processAlgorithm
> KeyError: 'id'

EDIT: I solved the problem by initializing the new QgsFeature with my defined Fields variable. See below:

```
newEdge = QgsFeature(outFields)
```

Comment: Did my answer help you with you with your problem?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but still encounter an error. Please have a look to my edited question above! Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to see that it works now! I think you forgot do set the features fields (´feat.setFields(your_fields)´) but initializing the fields with the feature seems to work fine as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example of a possible base-layout of your `processAlgorithm()` method (just a quick wrap-up of the basic field related code you were asking about - has to be embedded into your context):

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    #get your input layers
    inEdges = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, 
                   self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_EDGES, context)
    inNodes = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, 
                   self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_NODES, context)

    #define your fields
    your_fields = QgsFields()

    #append fields
    your_fields.append(QgsField('id', QVariant.String))
    your_fields.append(QgsField('vto', QVariant.Double))
    your_fields.append(QgsField('vfrom', QVariant.Double))
    your_fields.append(QgsField('priority', QVariant.Int))
    your_fields.append(QgsField('node1', QVariant.String))
    your_fields.append(QgsField('node2', QVariant.String))

    #create the output sink
    (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_MERGED, context, your_fields, inEdges.wkbType(), inEdges.sourceCrs())

    #do some calculations with inEdges and inNodes

    #somewhere in your while/for loops create a new feature object
    feat = QgsFeature()

    #set your fields of the feature
    feat.setFields(your_fields)

    #set the attribute values like this 
    feat['vto'] = #some_vto_value

    #set geometry of feature
    feat.setGeometry(geom)

    #add feature to sink
    sink.addFeature(feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)        

    #return feature sink
    results = {}
    results[self.OUTPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_MERGED] = dest_id
    return results
```

The following steps are necessary to output a sink with custom fields (see corresponding code comments):

1. get your input layers
2. define your fields as `QgsFields` object
3. append the corresponding `QgsField` objects to the `QgsFields`
4. create the output `QgsFeatureSink` using the fields from the variable `your_fields`
5. do your calculations with the `inEdges` and `inNodes` layers
6. create features using `your_fields`, set their attributes and geometry in the calculation process
7. add the features to the `sink`
8. return the `sink` as new output layer.

Comment: hey @root676 ! I have tried your solution but I still get some error when trying to set an attribute value of the feature (it says KeyError: 'id' when writing newFeature['id'] = edgeid. I have edited my question so please have a look!